# Create/Delete Wordpress Installations from a web interface in a server

Tags: php, wordpress

is it possible to install/delete wordpress installations through a simple web interface(written in php)?

after hours of researching.. my understanding is that it could be possible with WP-CLI.

Maybe run the wp-cli command with php shell_exec upon a form submission.

the form could contain these fields:

```
Site Name:

Description:

username:

Password:
```

Upon submitting the info is it possible to create a wordpress installation in a server(local) with the submitted info?

and could the same process work for deleting the installation?

I am in the right path? are there any other ways of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I wouldn't do it that way.  Why not just clone a database and a directory, updating the configuration values?

Comment: clone the database and directory with WP-CLI? is that possible?

Comment: Never used wp-cli, but you can with PHP.

Comment: Do you know of any ready made php script that I can look into?